# extjs model override

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to override the base model class so it affects all my models. I basically need a single place where I check for any operation error so I can handle it instead of repeating my code all over the place so, in case of an error in any of my models, I get to manage it:

```
Ext.override(Ext.data.Model, {
    listeners: {
        failure: function (proxy, response, operation) {
            if(!operation.success) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('An error occurred', operation.error);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that it doesn't do anything on failure. I'm loading my overrides.js file last by the way.

Comment: That is because ´Model´ doesn't have a 'failure' event. You can override that in ´Ext.Ajax´ wich is the singleton `Ext.data.Connection`, check: [Ext.Ajax](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax)

Comment: Forgot about this. Too much work. Thanks man. Please post your answer so I can award it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `Model` doesn't have a 'failure' event.

You can override that in `Ext.Ajax` wich is the singleton `Ext.data.Connection`, 
check the docs for [Ext.Ajax](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax)

Example:

```
Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', function ( conn, response, options, eOpts ) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('An error occurred');
    });
```